# Designing a star / snowflake schema database

Tags: database, postgresql, database-design, architecture, data-warehouse

I have to design and build a star / snowflake schema database that will keep data about employees in a company - especially the rates that are payed to the employees. This is the first time I am experimenting with this schema type and I'm not sure about which parts of the fact tables should be separate dimension tables.

I don't exactly understand the practical upsides of having this schema, is it actually that much easier to perform queries on this type of database? Or is it only about the performance?

Below I am attaching the project of the schema of my database. I would like to know what should I modify for this to be the best possible version for this database. I also have a question about two things:

1. Should the `rate` column be just a value in the fact table? Or should it be a foreign key to a dim_rate table?
2. What about date dimensions? Should they just be values in specific tables? Or should they always be foreign keys? If they should be foreign keys, should there be one `dim_date` table or a table for each type of date?

As an example for question 2 lets takie the dim_employee table and the `employment_date` and `end_of_employment` columns. I have these dates as values in the `dim_employee` table but I can think of 2 other versions of how to handle this data: either foreign keys to a `dim_date` table or seperate fact tables for `fact_start_of_employment` and `fact_end_of_deployment`. I know I will need different kinds of report for example reports showing how many people started work and left the company for different date intervals (eg. in december of 2020). Honestly at this point I have no idea which option would be best and easiest to work with in the future.

Also as I said - I would love any constructive criticism of this schema, even if it means completely redesigning it.

[image]

Comment: [Data Warehouse Tutorial](https://www.guru99.com/data-warehousing.html)

Comment: This doesn't really answer my questions. This article explains the concepts of a data warehouse, I am looking for hands down implementation tips. Thanks tho

Answer (score 1):

I would merge both fact tables because I think there is a strong relation between rate and position. But that's how I look at this data without knowing all the details.

I would also create a date dimension and a form_of_employment dimension.

That would result in 4 dimensions:

- dim_employee
- dim_date
- dim_position
- dim_form_of_employment

And a single fact table with these columns:
fact_assignment

- employee_id
- date_id
- position_id
- form_of_employment_id
- rate
- student

This setup results in a proper star and very simpel SQL for your reports

Answer (score 0):

For every BI or reporting system, you have a process of designing your tables and building them based on that design. This process is called dimensional modeling. Some others call it data warehouse design, which is the same thing. Dimensional modeling is the process of thinking and designing the data model including tables and their relationships. As you see, there is no technology involved in the process of dimensional modeling, It is all happening on your head and ends up with sketching diagrams on the paper. Dimensional modeling is not the diagram in which tables are connected to each other, it is the process of doing that.

Star Schema is the best way of designing a data model for reporting, You will get the best performance and also flexibility using such a model.

In this case the Employee Dimension will be a [Historical Dimension or Slowly Changing Dimension](https://www.datawarehouse4u.info/SCD-Slowly-Changing-Dimensions.html) :

[image]

You can use a [bridge table](https://www.kimballgroup.com/2014/05/design-tip-166-potential-bridge-table-detours/).
In a classic dimensional schema, each dimension attached to a fact table has a single value consistent with the fact table’s grain. But there are a number of situations in which a dimension is legitimately multivalued.
Like in your example, an employee can have many positions :

[image]